# Using sharepoint for booking advising appointments

Tags: office-365, office

To encourage community college students to see their advisors, the advisors want to allow students to book appointments (30 minute increments) online. The students can sign in into their SharePoint 
account, select their advisor (majors and advisors given from a MS-Excel spreadsheet). After students sign in, they can enter their preferred e-mail addresses(as they use Yahoo, Gmail more than their 
community college email) and cell phone numbers so that text and email reminders are sent before their appointment.

After selecting their advisor, students will be directed to a calendar to select the day and time for their appointment with the advisor. Then, the student's advisor is sent a calendar 
request on their community college email(which they access using Outlook) and if the advisor accepts that, students are sent an email and text confirmation (with another confirmation sent the day before the 
appointment TEXT ONLY). Once an advisor's 10 a.m. slot for Feb 23 is booked when he accepts a meeting request at that time, another student should not see that time as available. 
After the advising session students are sent a text satisfaction survey.

We are using Office 365 so SharePoint and Outlook should be integrated.

1. Can this be done using SharePoint in Office 365?
2. If not, what are the other ways?

Comment: Hi Chris! Do students and advisor use Outlook in Office 365? If they do, it would be easier to use the calendar in Outlook (Office 365)...

Comment: Hi Benny, Thanks for the reply. Yes, use Outlook in Office 365, but how can text reminders be sent out before the appointment? Also, how can a text satisfaction survey be sent out after the appointment?